# WP7 Tiles with PNG and Custom Colors

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, dynamic, png

Is it somehow possible to add a dynamic Tile in WP7, where i take a PNG file with my logo in the Center and add a Background Color to it?

It should look like this:

[image]

At the moment i create my Tiles like this:

```
private void addShortcut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Url = GlobalVariables.Uri;
        StandardTileData NewTileData = new StandardTileData
        {
            BackgroundImage = new Uri("img/red.jpg", UriKind.Relative),
            Title = "Energy "+GlobalVariables.Name,
            Count = 0,
            BackTitle = "Radion Energy",
            BackContent = "Hitmusic Only!",
            BackBackgroundImage = new Uri("img/test.jpg", UriKind.Relative)
        };
        try
        {
            // Create the Tile and pin it to Start. This will cause a navigation to Start and a deactivation of our application.
            ShellTile.Create(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?stationName=" + stationName + "&tile=true&name=" + GlobalVariables.Name + "&url=" + Url, UriKind.Relative), NewTileData);
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Channel-Tile exists already.");
        }
    }
```

So at the moment the Background has always the same color as the Phonestyle itself. (I don't really get why because the red.jpg actually is a red square. :) And at the moment i dont have a Logo in it so it's just blanc.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the Ree7 Tile Toolkit, which allows to you setup a tile with a custom background color, the source code includes a sample project which explains and demonstrates how to use the toolkit :-

http://wp7tiletoolkit.codeplex.com/

Comment: so there is no way to do it with the WP7 Library without a toolkit?

Comment: There probably is, based on creating an image with a particular background colour. What the toolkit does is create background tile images on the fly, referencing them from isolated storage, therefore removing the need to include every different possible colour as an image in your project.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I try to implement this in my Project :) I hope it works^^

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that your image is set to "Content"?

Comment: How do you mean if it is set to Content? I dont find a Attribte in there saying Content except for "BackContent" where i already have set the string: "Hitmusik only!"

Comment: ok i found what you meant... but wasn't excactly that what i was looking for. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
private const string FLICKR_LIVE_TILE = "/Shared/ShellContent/flickr_live_tile.jpg";
private const string FLTile = "/Shared/ShellContent/FLTile.jpg";
```

prepare `WriteableBitmap` with whatever source you want

```
IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
                if (myIsolatedStorage.FileExists(FLTile))
                {
                    myIsolatedStorage.DeleteFile(FLTile);
                }
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream iso = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(FLTile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()))
                {
                    WriteableBitmap1 .SaveJpeg(iso, 768, 200, 0, 100);
                    iso.Close();
                }
                if (myIsolatedStorage.FileExists(FLICKR_LIVE_TILE))
                {
                    myIsolatedStorage.DeleteFile(FLICKR_LIVE_TILE);
                }
                using (
             IsolatedStorageFileStream isoFileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(FLICKR_LIVE_TILE, FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
             IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()))
                {
                    WriteableBitmap2 .SaveJpeg(isoFileStream, 336, 200, 0, 100);
                    isoFileStream.Close();
                }




                var shellTileData = new FlipTileData
                {
                    BackgroundImage = new Uri("isostore:" + FLICKR_LIVE_TILE, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute),
                    //BackContent = "Connectivity Slab",
                    SmallBackgroundImage = new Uri("isostore:" + FLICKR_LIVE_TILE, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute),
                    WideBackgroundImage = new Uri("isostore:" + FLTile, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute),
                    WideBackBackgroundImage = new Uri("isostore:" + FLTile, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute),
                    BackBackgroundImage = new Uri("isostore:" + FLICKR_LIVE_TILE, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute),
                };
                var tile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First();
                tile.Update(shellTileData);
```

it will help to create both wide and short tile images

Answer (score 0):

If it shows just a Square then you have set the URI of the Picture not correctly :-)

edit: The Images should be set on "Content" too (already mentioned)